# App freezes when looping through the pixels of screen in iOS

Tags: ios, screen, pixel

I am using the for loop to go through each pixel of screen.

```
for (int x_axis=0; x_axis<screenWidth; x_axis++)
{
    for (int y_axis=0; y_axis<screenHeight; y_axis++)
    {
        // some code 
    }
}
```

Now what happens is that it is going through all the pixels of screen due to which app freezes. Is there any other way I can loop through each pixel of screen and app will not freeze. Please help

Ok, what I want is to know what is the color of each pixel and so I am using this 2 for loops. Please can someone say, how can I get the color of all the pixels of screen. I know how to know the color of each pixel. But, I want to check each pixel color, I will have to loop through all the pixels of the screen.

Comment: What are you performing in the loop? some more code will help.

Comment: checking the pixel color. But that doesn't matter. What my question is how to reduce the time of this loop execution.

Comment: Your code does not mean that you are looping through the pixels. Please extract your question

Comment: Comment your //Some code. I mean the functionality and run it and check it crashes

Answer (score 0):

maybe your code is just slow? it can take minutes to iterate through all pixels of the screen if you are using a bad algorithm. You can put something like `NSLog(@"looping. x_axis=%d", x_axis);` just before the inner loop to see how fast your algorithm is or wheter it crashes anywhere or is just slooow

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatch_async

Create new dispatch queue (executing your code on the main queue causes your app to freeze)

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("My new Q",NULL);
```

Then dispatch your loop on this queue like so:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
for (int x_axis=0; x_axis<screenWidth; x_axis++)
{
    for (int y_axis=0; y_axis<screenHeight; y_axis++)
    {
        // some code 
    }
}
});
```

This will run your code asynchronous and wont block your main thread, also going through every pixel on the screen is a bit of an overkill. If you want to see exactly how long does it take to run your code change the code above with this:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];
    for (int x_axis=0; x_axis<screenWidth; x_axis++)
    {
        for (int y_axis=0; y_axis<screenHeight; y_axis++)
        {
            // some code 
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Time: %d", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime]); //in seconds
    });
```

Running this loop as it is returns a value of :0.027331sec. If I replace "// some code" with 
`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"X_AXIS:%d Y_AXIS:%d",x_axis, y_axis]` and add it to an array the time goes to 0.463264sec. So if you're checking the colour of each pixel it will take a lot of time to complete.

Please let me know if this helps.